# Insert Null into database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I must insert some values into a database table with Entity Framework, 2 or 3 must be added, the others must get `null` value.

I use Entity Framework in asp.net mvc

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: i tried .attach() instead .Add() but i doesn't work all the time

Comment: so edit your question with the snippet code

Comment: did u tried "?"  before your datatypes  for the values that need to assign null value !!

Comment: sorry didn't checked the answer! u can use "Nullable" or "?"

Comment: yes i tried this it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 2 steps you should do:

- Make sure the colums on database are nullable
- Don't make any assignment to the field prior to adding and saving.

Let's say you have an entity model class like:

```
public partial class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Salt { get; set; }
}
```

You can do:

```
DbEntities.Companies.Add(new Company{Id = 1, Status = 1});
DbEntities.SaveChanges();
```

This would cause all the fields -except the ones we set with object initializer- to be `null` on database.